# How to include proxy for phantomjs in selenium webdriver in java with user name and password

Tags: java, proxy, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

i have been wondering for a while a way to provide **proxy credentials for phantomJs in selenium webdriver in java** after my own course of research i thought it is done but nevertheless i am still receiving **407**(proxy issue) i have provided my code below for your kind review, help would be greatly appriciated

```
     public class PhantomProxy {

         private static PhantomJSDriverService service;  
         private static WebDriver webDriver;  
         protected static DesiredCapabilities dCaps;  
         public static void main(String[] args) {
             String[]a={"--proxy=ip:10....(your proxy ip)","--proxy-auth=username:password"};
            service = new PhantomJSDriverService.Builder()  
            .usingPhantomJSExecutable(new File("your own custom path\\phantomjs.exe"))  
            .usingCommandLineArguments(a).usingPort(6050).build();  

           service.start();  

                Capabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
                    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);                
                    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);  

                    webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), caps);  
                    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 

                    webDriver.get("http://www.google.com");
                     Thread.sleep(2000L);
                     String pageSource=webDriver.getPageSource();
                       System.out.println(pageSource);
                      webDriver.quit();      
    }
```

it is to be noted that the command line arguments works fine in command line interface but i completely have no idea why it doesn't works here

Answer (score 0):

Here is a part of code that works for me with phantomJs 2.0.0 on windows

```
private static void phantomJsDriver() {
    final String pathToPhantom = phantomJsPath();
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
      capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, pathToPhantom);
    capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCapabilities());
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
}

private static List<String> cliArgsCapabilities() {
    List<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<String>();
    cliArgsCap.add("--proxy=url:port");
    cliArgsCap.add("--proxy-auth=user:pass");
    cliArgsCap.add("--proxy-type=http");
    return cliArgsCap;
}
```

You just need to changes lines with you own values for proxy

```
cliArgsCap.add("--proxy=url:port");
cliArgsCap.add("--proxy-auth=user:pass");
```